# Menu link not working - super coding newb here

Tags: html

line 59 of my code i put an image in my menu to link to another page, all it does is freeze the page, on the page i hover over it, and it shows its going to the right place, if i right click and open it in a new tab it goes there, but the link/image itself does not.

http://www.7daygrind.com/js/jquery.min.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
        <title>7 day grind</title>
     <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
<!-- 
Nature Theme 
http://www.templatemo.com/tm-398-nature
-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        
        <!-- Google Web Font Embed -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,500,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo_main.css">
        <style type="text/css">
        biztitle1 {
 font-family: gabriola;
}
        .no-js body #main-wrapper .col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.affix.text-center .templatemo-site-title a {
 font-family: gabriola;
}
        .no-js body #main-wrapper .col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.affix.text-center .templatemo-site-title b {
 font-family: Mardian Demo;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-wrapper">
            <!--[if lt IE 7]>
                <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a rel="nofollow" href="http://browsehappy.com">upgrade your browser</a> or <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 affix text-center" style="z-index: 1;">
                <h1 class="templatemo-site-title">&nbsp;</h1>
                <h1 class="templatemo-site-title"><img src="images/btn-menu.png" alt="main menu" id="m-btn" class="pull-right visible-xs visible-sm" >
                </h1>

                <ul id="responsive" style="display:none" class="hidden-lg hidden-md"></ul><!-- /.responsive --></div>
          <div class="menu visible-md visible-lg">
              <ul id="menu-list">
                    <li class="active home-menu"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                        <li class="services-menu"><a href="#services">Our Services</a></li>
                    <li class="services-menu1"><a href="#services1">- Integrated</a></li>
                    <li class="services-menu2"><a href="#services2">- Soul-Fit-Trition</a></li>
                <li class="services-menu3"><a href="#services3">- Boot-camp</a></li>
                    <li class="about-menu"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="store-menu"><a href="#store">Store</a></li>
                    <li class="testimonial-menu"><a href="#testimonial">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li class="contact-menu"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="blog-menu"><a href="http://blog.7daygrind.com" target="_parent"> <img src="images/blogbutton.jpg" width="100" height="50"></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.menu -->
    <div class="image-section">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/nature1.jpg" id="home-img" class="main-img inactive" alt="Home">
                    <img src="images/kettlebells.jpg" id="about-img" class="inactive" alt="About">
                    <img src="images/nature2.jpg" id="services-img"  class="inactive" alt="Services">
                     <img src="images/nature2.jpg" id="services1-img"  class="inactive" alt="Services1">
                      <img src="images/nature2.jpg" id="services2-img"  class="inactive" alt="Services2">
                       <img src="images/boot-camp2.jpg" id="services3-img"  class="inactive" alt="Services3">
                       <img src="images/nature1.jpg" id="store-img" class="inactive" alt="Store">
                    <img src="images/nature5bbb.jpg" id="testimonial-img" class="inactive" alt="Testimonial">
                    <img src="images/stretch.jpg" id="contact-img" class="inactive" alt="Contact">
                    
                  <img src="images/nature1.jpg" id="blog-img" class="inactive" alt="Blog">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Clicking the image does open the link in the same tab. What exactly is not working?

Comment: go to page www.7daygrind.com and click the blog image in the menu, it goes no where

Comment: It should work, well try target = "_blank" on your blog image link instead of parent.

Comment: nope, still nothing

Comment: Clicking the link on www.7daygrind.com throws a console error
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: imghttp://blog.7daygrind.com-img.
You should probably fix this.

Comment: The error indicated by @Raghav is thrown by `jquery.min.js` — this suggests that you are using jQuery somewhere outside the code sample you've included to alter the behavior of the link. If this is the case, you will have to include that code to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: You have to use jquery with careful as i disabled the js in browser then run your site and it was working so please re add your js files.

Comment: i added a link to the file in my question, glad you understand it, cause its a lot of random code to me haha.

Comment: The culprit is in the script `templatemo_script.js` loaded at the bottom of your code. Most of this code is used to modify links matched by `$("#menu-list a)`, and includes lines like `var imgSrc = $("img"+name+"-img").attr('src');`, which would explain the error @Raghav points out.

Comment: That's true you need to fix your templatemo_script.js, that's where all error took place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**`JQuery`  On your page blocking the `default` function on `a`. Try this to redirect page on click.

```
<script>    
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $(".blog-menu a").click(function(){
            window.location='http://blog.7daygrind.com';
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why jquery for such a simple click?? He has to fix the js error and that's it.

Comment: Yes, He can fix this with that way too. but it will surely work that is the reason i added this answer @Leothelion

Comment: @Leothelion The error is caused by a script (`templatemo_script.js`) loaded at the bottom of the page, which may accomplish some generally-useful things but present this one unwanted side-effect. A patch like the one in this answer would be appropriate in that case.

Comment: anywhere after the jQuery library file. inside <script> tag

Comment: use it in your footer after `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @LeeLaudy - i updated the code try it again. i fix the error

Comment: haha you totally fixed it, you guys rock. thanks for the help

Comment: happy to help and accept this answer as right one @LeeLaudy